# How to send an alert to the contact when preventing a case to reopen?

Tags: before-trigger, visual-flows, before-save-flow

I have a scenario, where closed cases (opened by customers through email reply) can not re-open after 2 weeks.

I am managing everything via Flows (before create/update). Is it possible to send an email alert to the customer, that his case couldn't be re-opened, and he needs to send a new email ?

When using the 'Before Create/update' visual flow, there is no option to send email alerts, I assume cause of DML restrictions.

With @cropredy suggestion, here's what I get:

New field on case: **Late_Reopen_attempt__c**

[image]

Flow: **Case Before Create/Update**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**** The main problem with this scenario, is that the data is saved to the case record. This is something I want to avoid.

So, I added a validation rule on the case:
[image]

But I get to a race condition, where I don't want any updates, but only to switch the Checkbox indicator.

Comment: why not set a field on Case `Has_Late_Arriving_Reopen_Attempt__c` to true, evaluate this in an after Save Flow - send email, then toggle it back to false?

Comment: thanks, I tried to implement, but got other issues. see original question. thank you

Comment: well - before save flows can't do anything but update the record that triggered the flow so I don't see how you solve this without a toggle, change your VR to be toggle aware, and  after save flow

Comment: @cropredy I can't figure out your idea. Can you please elaborate, and/or give an example?

Answer (score 1):

A suggested procedure (apologies that my first suggestion was ill-formed for your use case)

- Create a field on Case called `Late_Arrival_Count__c` (type number, default to 0)
- In Before Save flow, increment `Late_Arrival_Count` by 1 if email has arrived after case was closed post 14 days.
- Adjust any VR that prevents a Case from being updated post +14 day of close date to return FALSE if `Has_Late_Arriving_Reopen_Attempt__c > 0 AND Has_Late_Arriving_Reopen_Attempt__c has changed`
- Have an After Save Flow that inspects the value of `Has_Late_Arriving_Reopen_Attempt__c` - if has changed, use Email Action